# raster resolution not displaying properly

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm seeing some strange behavior when I plot a certain raster. 
This is a shaded relief raster I acquired from naturalearthdata.com.[You can download it here.](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-gray-earth/50m-gray-earth-with-shaded-relief-and-water/)

I find that depending on what spatial scale I plot the raster at, it plots a different resolution, despite the resolution of the raster not being changed.

```
library(raster)
relief <- raster('GRAY_50M_SR_W.tif')

# let's use Mexico as an example:
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
mx <- wrld_simpl[which(wrld_simpl@data$NAME == 'Mexico'),]

# Here I create a cropped version of the raster
reliefMX <- crop(relief, mx)
```

To illustrate the problem, I plot Mexico to get the map extent, then I plot the full extent of the raster, and then the cropped raster on top.

You can see that the rasters show very different resolutions, but they really have identical resolutions.

```
plot(mx)
plot(relief, col = grey(0:100/100), legend = FALSE, axes = F, box = F, add=T)
plot(reliefMX, col = grey(0:100/100), legend = FALSE, axes = F, box = F, add=T)

> res(relief)
[1] 0.03333333 0.03333333
> res(reliefMX)
[1] 0.03333333 0.03333333
```

[image]

Any ideas? How can I get these rasters to display properly?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] maptools_0.9-2 raster_2.5-8   sp_1.2-4      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0  rgdal_1.2-7     tools_3.4.0     foreign_0.8-68  Rcpp_0.12.10   
[6] grid_3.4.0      lattice_0.20-35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the `maxpixels` argument in the call to `raster::plot`:

> maxpixels 
>   integer > 0. Maximum number of cells to use for the plot. If maxpixels < ncell(x), sampleRegular is used before plotting. If gridded=TRUE maxpixels may be ignored to get a larger sample

When you plot the "full" map, the image is automatically downsampled to save you memory and reduce the rendering time. You can change the value of `maxpixels' to get the desired level of "detail". see for example:

```
plot(relief, col = grey(0:100/100), legend = FALSE, axes = F, box = F, add=F)
```

[image]

```
plot(relief, col = grey(0:100/100), legend = FALSE, axes = F, box = F, add=F, maxpixels = 5000000)
```

[image]

Although at this "zoom level" is not evident, the second image is more detailed. You can appreciate this by "zooming in" on your cropped area:

```
plot(mx)
plot(relief, col = grey(0:100/100), legend = FALSE, axes = F, box = F, add = T, maxpixels = 5000000)
```

[image]

Still not "good" as the a-priori cropped one (since I'm still not using "all" pixels), but already better.

In practice, it's all a compromise between rendering time/memory and quality of the output. Obviously, if you just need to plot a part of the area, it's much more efficient to crop the image beforehand.

HTH.